# How to pipe attachment to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I would like to pipe an attachement from inside a *.mka to a variable instead of to a file.

Saving the attachment to a *.txt file looks like this (and works):

```
import io
import subprocess
import sys, os
import soundfile as sf

full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
path, filex = os.path.split(full_path)

fname = 'my_own_soundfile.mka'
fullpath = path + '\\' + fname
pathffmpeg = 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe'

command = [pathffmpeg, "-dump_attachment:t:0",
           "C:\folder\\attachment.txt",
           "-i", fullpath] # This one works

proc = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This command is my attempt at piping the attachment, however this does not work:

```
command = [pathffmpeg, "-dump_attachment:t:0",
           "-f", "PIPE:0",
           "-i", fullpath]
```

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For piping stdout content, replace output file name argument with "pipe:"

- Subprocess command (`"pipe:1"` or `"pipe:"`):

  ```
   command = [pathffmpeg, "-dump_attachment:t:0",
      "pipe:1",
      "-i", fullpath]
  ```
- For reading `sdtout` content, add `.stdout` after the run command:

  ```
   attachment = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
  ```

The result format is bytes array.

---

Here is a complete code sample:

```
import subprocess

fname = 'my_own_soundfile.mka'

# For piping stdout content, replace output file name argument with "pipe:".
command = ["ffmpeg", "-dump_attachment:t:0", "pipe:", "-i", fname]

# Execute FFmpeg as subprocess and read from stdout pipe (attachment is "bytes array").
attachment = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

attachment_str = attachment.decode("utf-8")  # Convert from bytes array to string (converting to string is optional).
```

Comment: Thank you, your code works. I've learned that capitalizing `'PIPE:'` does not work, but lowercase does work. Also the `'-f'` flag had to go.